# Rename duplicate Keys in Json array data

Tags: json, key, rename, jq, jtc

I have a json data as below.

```
{
"Data":
[
"User": [
      {"Name": "Solomon", "Age":20}, 
      {"Name": "Absolom", "Age":30}, 
   ] 
"Country": [
       {"Name" : "US", "Resident" : "Permanent"},
       {"Name" : "UK", "Resident" : "Temporary"}
]]}
```

There are two tags with same keys,
in `Users` there is `Name` key and in `Country` also i have `Name` key. I need to preprocess the json file to differentiate the keys. My expected result is below. Tried through awk and sed commands, but i could not find proper solution. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Expected result:

```
{
"Data":
[
"User": [
      {"User_Name": "Solomon", "User_Age":20}, 
      {"User_Name": "Absolom", "User_Age":30}, 
   ] 
"Country": [
       {"Country_Name" : "US", "Country_Resident" : "Permanent"},
       {"Country_Name" : "UK", "Country_Resident" : "Temporary"}
]]}
```

Tag name should be appended to the attribute name.

This is what i have tried,

```
jq '[.[] | .["User_Name"] = .Name]' file_name.json
```

But it changes for both the tages `User` as well as `Country`

Comment: Your example is an invalid JSON value.

Comment: Its a valid Json file and have a data set with me.

Comment: Json array can also have key value pairs, for example, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: someone will provide you with a **jq** solution, while here I can offer you a `jtc` based: `<file.json jtc -tc -w'<Data>l[:]<L>k<.*>L:<>k' -u'"{L}_{}";'` - that's input invariant solution. PS. I'm the creator of `jtc` unix tool.

Comment: Oh that's nice. Can you explain in detail

Comment: You can use jq to pinpoint problems with your sample input and output (e.g. jq empty FILENAME), or use an online checker, e.g. jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1):

with the permission of the OP, here's a `jtc` based solution while waiting for the **jq**'s (assuming the input JSON is fixed):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Data>l[:]<L>k<.*>L:<>k' -u'"{L}_{}";' -tc
{
   "Data": {
      "Country": [
         { "Country_Name": "US", "Country_Resident": "Permanent" },
         { "Country_Name": "UK", "Country_Resident": "Temporary" }
      ],
      "User": [
         { "User_Age": 20, "User_Name": "Solomon" },
         { "User_Age": 30, "User_Name": "Absolom" }
      ]
   }
}
bash $
```

Explanation of the jtc parameters:

1. `-w'<Data>l[:]<L>k<.*>L:<>k'` :

- *walk path* (`-w`) selects `Data` label (`<Data>l`)
- and then each of the nested elements (`[:]`),
- and memorizes its key/label into the namespace `L` (`<L>k`),
- then finds further *each labeled* element using *REGEX label search* (`<.*>L:`)
- and finally *reinterpret* found element's key/label as the value (`<>k`)

2. `-u'"{L}_{}";'`:

- for each found label (in step 1) update operation (`-u`) is applied using template
- `"{L}_{}";'`, where `{L}` is *interpolated* with preserved in the namespace `L` value and `{}` is getting interpolated with the currently found label (at the each iteration of the *walk path*)
- the trailing `;` (or any other symbol) is required to distinguish the argument of `-u` from a literal JSON.

`-tc` is used to display JSON in a semi-compact form.

PS. I'm the creator of `jtc` unix JSON processing tool. The disclaimer is required by SO.

Comment: Thank you. How to install jtc module?

Comment: [`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) is easy to [compile](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc#compilation-and-installation-options), or download the [pre-compiled](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc#linux-and-macos-precompiled-binaries-are-available-for-download) linux/macOS version.

Answer (score 1):

As originally posted, neither the illustrative input nor the corresponding output is valid JSON, but the following has been tested using JSON based on the shown input:

```
.Data |= (  (.User    |= map(with_entries(.key |= ("User_" + .))))
          | (.Country |= map(with_entries(.key |= ("Country_" + .)))) )
```

Of course, the above may need tweaking depending on the actual requirements, and can be generalized in various ways, e.g. as shown below.

### A generalization

```
.Data |= with_entries( (.key + "_") as $newkey
                       | .value |= map(with_entries(.key |= ($newkey + .))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we convert the same data to csv?

Comment: Yes, most likely using `@csv`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using jq [Streaming](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming)

```
fromstream(tostream | .[0] |= if length < 4 then . else .[3]="\(.[1])_\(.[3])" end)
```

It works by using [tostream](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostream) to convert your input to a stream of arrays

```
[["Data","Country",0,"Name"],"US"]
[["Data","Country",0,"Resident"],"Permanent"]
[["Data","Country",0,"Resident"]]
[["Data","Country",1,"Name"],"UK"]
[["Data","Country",1,"Resident"],"Temporary"]
[["Data","Country",1,"Resident"]]
[["Data","Country",1]]
[["Data","User",0,"Age"],20]
[["Data","User",0,"Name"],"Solomon"]
[["Data","User",0,"Name"]]
[["Data","User",1,"Age"],30]
[["Data","User",1,"Name"],"Absolom"]
[["Data","User",1,"Name"]]
[["Data","User",1]]
[["Data","User"]]
[["Data"]]
```

then applying a simple update assignment [|=](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=) expression to transform the stream into

```
[["Data","Country",0,"Country_Name"],"US"]
[["Data","Country",0,"Country_Resident"],"Permanent"]
[["Data","Country",0,"Country_Resident"]]
[["Data","Country",1,"Country_Name"],"UK"]
[["Data","Country",1,"Country_Resident"],"Temporary"]
[["Data","Country",1,"Country_Resident"]]
[["Data","Country",1]]
[["Data","User",0,"User_Age"],20]
[["Data","User",0,"User_Name"],"Solomon"]
[["Data","User",0,"User_Name"]]
[["Data","User",1,"User_Age"],30]
[["Data","User",1,"User_Name"],"Absolom"]
[["Data","User",1,"User_Name"]]
[["Data","User",1]]
[["Data","User"]]
[["Data"]]
```

then reversing the transformation with [fromstream](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#fromstream(stream_expression)).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5Pa8JAEMXv@RSPPRmQYE1P0hxCexNKUXNKF1nJxD9kd@vuepDqZ093Y2grYulp3pvfvOHt9m1bGy2tMyTkAE5fFE5IyhHHKcO2RkNq7TZ4wiPchhQSUGPJX6QcGdj7ICkfeLwMM@UxA6kKcdS2nxHAXoQTbIKgvSssGe/KzqHfduRVSPKEzXWjpVZs@IPydSDjUb85D@@n85UN@dt0@p3uJr8csGd9UM4c/65UzH//m5HdVqRcIG9kpFDB/KNbMb33ZkHyQxvhe1yXjII6fwE)